Enumitem: Align several paragraphs of a same item
Consider the following description list:
\begin{description}
\item[Some term] 
    A first line of definition.

    A second paragraph of definition.
\item[Some other term]
    A first line of definition.

    A second paragraph of definition.
\end{description}

The result is the following:

My goal would be that in each definition "A second paragraph..." be (left) aligned with "A first line...". I have the impression that it should be possible using the length \labelwidth. My tentative so far is either \setlist[description]{listparindent=\labelwidth+\itemsep} but the + seems not to be accepted, or \setlist[description]{listparindent=\itemindent} but the result is the same as in the picture.
Is this possible with enumitem?

please can you make your code compilable?

Not with enumitem. I'll present a proof of concept that's mostly aimed at showing it's a bad idea. Caveat emptor.
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{funnydesc}{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\newcommand{\funnyitem}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\itemsep}%
  \settowidth{\leftskip}{\textbf{#1 }}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\leftskip][l]{\textbf{#1}}}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

Some text before the funny description environment,
so we see how it behaves with respect to the margins.

\begin{funnydesc}
\funnyitem{Some term} Here we describe the first term and we do
quite a long description taking a few lines; I hope that there
are at least three, so we can see the effect.

Now I go on with the description, again with some filler text
that fills a few lines.

\funnyitem{Some other term} Here we describe the other term and we do
quite a long description taking a few lines; I hope that there
are at least three, so we can see the effect.

Now I go on with the description, again with some filler text
that fills a few lines.

\funnyitem{Short} Here we describe the short term and we do
quite a long description taking a few lines; I hope that there
are at least three, so we can see the effect.

Now I go on with the description, again with some filler text
that fills a few lines.
\end{funnydesc}

Some text after the funny description environment,
so we see how it behaves with respect to the margins.

\end{document}



I am not convinced it is a bad idea… But maybe the reason is that description lists are not the best environment for what I need. Basically, my terms are all pretty short (even if not all of the same length) and each paragraph is usually one-line.
Anyway, thanks for both the proof of concept and the caveat!
